# Dynamically form not submitting properly AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to generate dynamically form in table and submit but there is problem in my code which is difficult for me solve,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnsummary').on('click', function() {
            var date = $('#dddeliverydate').val();
            var soid = $('#sssoid option:selected').val();

            $.ajax({
        url: "tblsum.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',

        data:
          
          "&date=" +
          date +
          "&soid=" +
          soid,

        success: function(response) {
            if ( response.length == 0 ) {
    alert("NO DATA FOUND!");
}
else{
        $("#tblsum tbody").empty();
            var len = response.length;
            
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var invoiceno = response[i].invoiceno;
                var shopname = response[i].shopname;
                var paymentmode = response[i].paymentmode;
                var finalamount = response[i].finalamount;
                if (finalamount==0){
                    return false
                }
                else if (paymentmode=="Credit"){
                    var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    
                    "<td align='center'>" + invoiceno + "<input type='hidden' name='invoiceno[]' value='"+invoiceno+"'></td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + shopname + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + paymentmode + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + finalamount + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'><input type='number' id='finalamount' name='finalamount[]' value='0'></td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#tblsum tbody").append(tr_str);

                }
                else{

                

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + invoiceno + "<input type='hidden' name='invoiceno[]' value='"+invoiceno+"'></td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + shopname + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + paymentmode + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + finalamount + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'><input type='number' id='finalamount' name='finalamount[]' value='" + finalamount + "'></td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#tblsum tbody").append(tr_str);

            }
        }
        $("#tblsum tbody").append("<tr><td colspan='5'><button class='btn btn-success' type='button' id='btnsum'onclick='summary()'>Save</button></td></tr>");
        }
    

        }
    })

        });
    })
```

There is two problem if final amount is 0 then save button did not appear, when I submit form first field which is invoiceno don't submit on next page,
below is submit function

```
function summary(){
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
       
        
            var date = $('#dddeliverydate').val();
            var soid = $('#sssoid option:selected').val();
            var form = $('#formsum').serialize();
            

            $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:
          "&date=" +
          date +
          "&soid=" +
          soid+
          "&form=" +
          form,
          success: function(data) {
            var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
    w.document.write(data);
    }
          
            })
        })
    }
```

Below is my PHP code.

```
for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['invoiceno']); $count++){
    $data = array(
    
        $invoiceno = $_POST['invoiceno'][$count],
        $amount = $_POST['finalamount'][$count],
);
echo "Invoice NO ".$invoiceno." Amount ".$amount.'<br>';
}
```

sorry for bad english.

Comment: Not that strange if you have `if (finalamount==0){return false}` The button is in de first `else{..}` so you will never reach it.

Comment: Thank you for your response but first else have nested if else.

Comment: You never reach that second else. `if(response.length==0){...} else{ ... for(var i=0;i<len;i++){ ... if(finalamount==0){return false} ...` Return doesn't break the `for-loop`, it's stopping the whole thing.

Comment: Put some `console.log()` in it to see what executes and where it stops.

Comment: can you plz regenerate correct code for me?

Comment: Need help guys I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

I told you before `return` **STOPS** executing a function, so all code after it is obsolete. In this case, when `finalamount == 0` you stop executing the function and return to the place where it started. So the code to create the submit button never will be reached. With some proper indentation, you could see that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //<< ===== START START START of onclick function
    $('#btnsummary').on('click', function() {
       ....                                                                
       $.ajax({                                                        
          url: "tblsum.php",
          ....
          success: function(response) {  
             if ( response.length == 0 ) { .... }
             else{
                $("#tblsum tbody").empty();
                ....
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                   var invoiceno = response[i].invoiceno;
                   var finalamount = response[i].finalamount;
                   ....                                                        
                   if (finalamount==0){                        
                      return false   
              // STOP EXECUTING THIS FUNCTION 
              // AND GO DIRECTLY TO END OF FUNCTION ================= >>
              // code after this will NOT be executed
                   }
                   else if (paymentmode=="Credit"){....}
                   else{....}
                }
              // if finalamount == 0, this will never be executed
                $("#tblsum tbody").append("<tr><td colspan='5'><button class='btn btn-success' type='button' id='btnsum'onclick='summary()'>Save</button></td></tr>");
             }
          }
       })
    });
    // ===== END END END of onclick function << ===============
    // continue executing script from here
})
```

So you could use [`continue`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) instead of [`return`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_return.asp) to skip only one itteration in the `for loop`.

Comment: Thank you Michel you partially resolve my problem, form submit not working properly the first field is not showing on submit page, Plz help

Comment: experts need your help I am stuck